# Android: Inflate XML OnClick?

Tags: java, android

Hello fellow programmers!

In my app I want some XML listed below to be inflated OnClick. It needs to be put into another LinearLayout.I also want to change the text in the TextView and the id's of the EditTexts to "ListItem"+numOfItems. How can I do this?

XML to be inflated:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:weightSum="100"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:text="1."
                        android:id="@+id/tvItem1"/>
                <EditText
                        android:layout_weight="90"
                        android:layout_width="100px"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:hint="List Item 1"
                        android:id="@+id/etItem1"
                        android:paddingTop="50px"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Full java class:

```
package com.frostbytedev.randomgenie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Steven on 6/23/13.
 */
public class Test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    java.util.List<TextView> listOfET = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    LinearLayout insideScroll;
    ScrollView svItems;
    TextView etItem1, etItem2;
    Button Add, Remove;
    int numOfItems = 2, width, height;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dynamictest);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        Add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        Remove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
        insideScroll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.insideScroll);
        etItem1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.etItem1);
        etItem2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.etItem2);
        svItems=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.svItems);
        Add.setOnClickListener(this);
        Remove.setOnClickListener(this);

        listOfET.add(etItem1);
        listOfET.add(etItem2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.bAdd:
                numOfItems += 1;
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                layout.setPadding(getDP(15f), 0, 0, 0);
                layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((getDP(80f)), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


                TextView numberView = new TextView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getDP(80f),getDP(10f));
                numberView.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
                numberView.setText(numOfItems + ".");
                layout.addView(numberView);

                EditText optionText = new EditText(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams etParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getDP(80f),getDP(100f));
                numberView.setLayoutParams(etParams);
                numberView.setHint("List Option "+numOfItems);
                layout.addView(optionText);

                insideScroll.addView(layout);

                break;
            case R.id. bRemove:

                listOfET.remove(numOfItems);
                numOfItems -= 1;
                break;

        }
    }

    private int getDP(float i) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = i;
        float fpixels = metrics.density * dp;
        int pixels = (int) (fpixels + 0.5f);
        return pixels;
    }

}
```

This is my java class

Answer (score 0):

Add the id´s to your XML items.....

```
       <LinearLayout
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewId"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="1."
                    android:id="@+id/tvItem1"/>
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextId"
                    android:layout_weight="90"
                    android:layout_width="100px"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:hint="List Item 1"
                    android:id="@+id/etItem1"
                    android:paddingTop="50px"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

....add this code to your listView onItemClickListener....

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {


       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
       View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
       //Get the textView in your xml to set the text in it
       TextView textView = theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
       textView.setText("Text on the textView");
       //Get the EditText in you xml to set the new id 
       EditText editText = theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
       editText.setId(position);
       //add the view into the LinearLayout container (global variable)
       insideScroll.addView(theInflatedView);

    }
});
```

If you are clicking a button to add items to a LinearLayout then....

your activity implements OnClickListener interface....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

setOnClickListener to your button....

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now you receive the click on you onClick method....

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

         switch(v.getId()){
           case R.id.buttonId:
               LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
               View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
               //Get the textView in your xml to set the text in it
               TextView textView = theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
               textView.setText("Text on the textView");
               //Get the EditText in you xml to set the new id 
               EditText editText = theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
               editText.setId(linearLayout.getChildCount()+1);
               //add the view into the LinearLayout (global variable)
               insideScroll.addView(theInflatedView);
           break;
      }
}
```

Comment: But I am using just OnClickListener and how do I put it into the current layout?

Comment: But you are using a listView , don´t you?